# Python Win32Com Pivot Tables How to select multiple items in the report filter

Tags: python, pivot-table, win32com

I have this pivot table function everything works fine in the code I just cannot figure out how to get it to select multiple items in the Report Filter.

I can get it to filter for one item using CurrentPage (I tried using multiple CurrentPage lines but it will only pick up on the first one). The only time it will select multiple items is when I remove blanks it will leave all items selected and only remove blanks but will not read Packaging and Direct Material as selections.

```
def insert_pt_field_set3(pt3):
    field_rows = {}
    field_rows['Business'] = pt3.PivotFields("Business")

    field_values = {}
    field_values['Amt'] = pt3.PivotFields("Amt")

    field_Pages = {}
    field_Pages['Type'] = pt3.PivotFields("Type")

    # insert row fields
   
    field_rows['Business'].Orientation = 1
    field_rows['Business'].Position = 1

    # insert values field
    
    field_values['Amt'].Orientation = 4
    field_values['Amt'].Function = -4157 # value reference (count = -4112)
    field_values['Amt'].NumberFormat = "#,##0"

    # insert Filter fields
  
    field_Pages['Type'].Orientation = 3
    field_Pages['Type'].Position = 1
    field_Pages['Type'].EnableMultiplePageItems = True
    field_Pages['Type'].PivotItems("Direct Material").Visible = True
    field_Pages['Type'].PivotItems("Packaging").Visible = True
    field_Pages['Type'].PivotItems("(blank)").Visible = False
```